# ListActivity CustomAdapter error, onListItemClick never works

Tags: android, listactivity, custom-adapter

Below you can see the code, i implemented a simple adapter for my listview.  But i can not get in to onListItemClick. can anyone has suggestions ?

actually it displays the list normally but i am not able to get onitemclick events . thanks in advance.

```
            public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {


        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                ArrayList<Frame> results = WebOperations
                        .loadList_Frame();
                myAdapter = new MyListAdapter(MyListActivity.this);
                myAdapter.internalList = results;

                setListAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        };

        @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(this, item + " please show toast!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        public static class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                public ArrayList<Frame> internalList;
                public LayoutInflater mInflater;
                public int pageCount = 0;
                public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
                    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }
                public int getCount() {
                    if (internalList == null)
                        return 0;
                    return internalList.size();
                }
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    if (internalList == null || internalList.size() < position)
                        return null;
                    return internalList.get(position);
                }
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    if (internalList == null || internalList.size() < position)
                        return 0;
                    return internalList.get(position).getId();
                }
                public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = arg1;
                    if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
                        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.entryrow, null);
                        try {
                            String gunlukText = String.format(" %s ",
                                    internalList.get(position).getKeyText().toString());
                            TextView entry = (TextView) v
                                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewEntryText);
                            entry.setText((CharSequence) gunlukText);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "errorrrrrrrrrrr");
                        }
                    }
                    return v;
                }

            }
            }
```

EDIT 1 : I am adding entry_row layout xml file below.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewEntryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Ana_Sayfa"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What views do you have in the row layout? It's only a `TextView`?

Comment: yes just now just a textview . but later i will add imageview etc.

Comment: By any chance the `TextView` that you inflate has on of the attributes `android:focusable` or `android:focusableInTouchMode` set to `true`?

Comment: not yet, i will try . your suggestion .

Comment: slukian thx . it got your idea.  it solved by adding event in getview . as stated below .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add onclicklistener into getView method just before return view.

```
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.w("position", position + "");
                }
            });
```

check if it helps..

Comment: thanks deepak you did a good suggestion .  in getview method I did what you suggested and it seems ok.  problem solved now.   but it seems something wrong to me that for an listactivity, onlistitemclick never works i am not able to understand this

Answer (score 2):

You should consider adding your listener to your listview :

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
       Toast.makeText(this, item + " please show toast!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you see, MyListActivity is already extending ListActivity. onListItemCLick is callback method which gets called automatically when user clicks on any list item. Please read the documentation of ListActivity.

Comment: This is what I do myself. Presumably onListItemClick only works for the listview built in to the ListActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Didi you try, on your layout/entryrow, to add the addStatesFromChildrenattribute and set it to true ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:addStatesFromChildren

Answer (score 0):

Please refer one of the good example given in API demo of custom BaseAdapter from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html Just override `onListItemCLicked` and check. It works perfectly fine. Try to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: all the android examples contain custom adapter for string types like this example..

Comment: I added my entryrow xml file. 2 i am callling notifydatasetchanged after i addded items to adapter , actully if you suggest something else i can try ?